# How can I draw a chart with percentages using SmartXLS?

Tags: java, excel, smartxls

I am trying to draw a chart in an xlsx file using Java. I found [SmartXLS](http://www.smartxls.com/indexj.htm) and decided to give it a try. So far, I managed to draw the charts correctly, but I can't seem to be able to display percentages on the chart. Any ideas how to do that?

**EDIT:**
I realized my question may not have been detailed enough.

I am trying to draw a Pie chart, where the percentages are added on the chart itself. Thanks to Michael, I know how to do it in cells, but I do not know how to do it on the chart.

**EDIT 2:** There is no mention of the problem in the SmartXLS documentation, which is why I am requesting help. I do not need anyone writing code for me, just which function can do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:
`rangeStyle.setCustomFormat("0.00%");`

See: http://www.smartxls.com/java/formatting.htm#vformat-number

[In this example](http://www.smartxls.com/java/pivot-table.htm), they are applying some formatting to a chart. It seems like it matters from what area you obtain your `rangeStyle` Object.

For instance, you can call it as `rangeStyle = workBook.getRangeStyle(1, 1, 2, 2);//get format from range B2:C3`.
The formatting you set applies to selection within the sheet, or the parameters passed to `getRangeStyle()` (defaults to whole stylesheet without parameters, otherwise a cell range).
Perhaps you can select the part of your chart instead of the original datacells, and then apply the formatting as before?

Comment: First, thank you for your fast answer :D. Second, I don't think this is what I am looking for. Your answer works very well for cells in a sheet, but I can't use it in charts, because I want to display the percentage on the chart itself.

Comment: Aha. I would assume that your chart is based on some underlying cells, though? Doesn't the formatting of the underlying cell propagate to the displayed text on the chart?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The chart is not affected by the format of the underlying cells.